# How does the first Control Point in Maintenance work?

Tags: control

How does the first Control Point in Maintenance work?

I cleansed it, got the location reset animation and everything, then managed to use it once, but then I had to cleanse it again, when I respawned, along with being unable to use it between cleans, and it had the blurry appearance of the unclean between my cleans...

I respawned because I died, I think.

Was it some strange glitch, and not because there was Hiss around it, preventing me from using it? As that didn't seem like a problem back in the Executive section...

Comment: What caused you to respawn? Did you die in combat, or were you reloading a save file?

Comment: @Stevoisiak - I think I died and never tried reloading?